# How do I do the command Alt+M T D in LyX?

Tags: lynx

I'm trying to learn to use LyX and I'm using Windows 7. The command to turn an inline equation into a display equation is "Alt+M T D". How do i press those buttons? I've tried pressing all four at the same time, and holding Alt while pressing the three letters in order. Neither worked.

Comment: Which OS, which application? And can be Alt+m, them t then d

Comment: It might help if you had some reference URL to what exactly it is you're trying to achieve

Comment: Windows 7, LyX. Thank you Romeo Ninov. it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LyX, you should press Alt+M (meta key as far as I remember), then T and then D